# NameError: name 'sec' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv

apenas estoy empezando con Python, y me surgió un pequeño problema. Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica que detecte el color azul y un reloj que empiece a contar tan pronto como se detecte el color. Si se quita el color azul de la camara, se detiene el reloj y se establece en 0 y se reinicia una vez que se detecta el color. Ya me había salido, y cuando lo quise volver a probar me salio ese error

> NameError: name 'sec' is not defined

Aquí mi código, espero que me puedan ayudar

```
azulBajo = np.array([94, 80, 2],np.uint8)
azulAlto = np.array([126, 255, 255],np.uint8)
video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
sec=0

def show_frame():
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        hsv=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
        bluemask= cv2.inRange(hsv,azulBajo, azulAlto)
        contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(bluemask,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
        for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
            area=cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if (area > 3000):
                x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                image=cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                cv2.putText(image,"Blue Color",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1.0,(255,0,0))
        if len(contours) > 0:
            global sec
            sec += 1
            labeltm.config(text=str(sec))
            labeltm.after(1000,show_frame)
        if len(contours) == 0:        
            labeltm.config(text="No hay color")
            sec=0       
                       
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        lblVideo.configure(image=image)
        lblVideo.image = image
        lblVideo.after(1000,show_frame)

labeltm= Label(frame1, text=str(sec), font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), bg="gray15", fg="white")
labeltm.place(x=250,y=150)
```

Comment: La declaración global también es afectada por los ifs, lo que significa que global sec solo se ejecuta cuando la condición que la engloba da verdadero. Te recomiendo colocar tus global al principio de la función.

Comment: Dante S. ya lo hice, no funcionó :( me marcó el mismo error

Comment: Seguro que lo pusiste al principio de la función? Fuera de todo condicional?

Comment: @DanteS. le puse abajo del `def show_frame()`  y no, no se si lo tengo que poner antes del def show_frame(), me gustaría ponerme en contacto contigo para que me ayudaras :) obvio si se puede!

Comment: Está bien que hablemos así, cualquier cosa paso la charla a un chat. En fin, entonces lo hiciste bien. Tu función de casualidad se ejecuta antes de que exista la variable sec?

Comment: no entendí bien, pero al momento de presionar el boton donde quiero que se vea la camara y todo, me marca ese error, la parte del color azul si funciona y todo bien, lo único que no es a partir de `if len(contours)`, ya puse el global antes y aun asi no :(

Comment: Podrías mostrarme un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para ver lo que puede estar pasando por favor?

Comment: segs=0
mins=0
def show_frame():                                                                                                              
    global segs, mins
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret:                                                                                                                               
   #parte de encontrar el color azul
    if len(contours) > 0:  
        segs += 1
        if segs == 60:
           segs = 0
            mins += 1
     labeltm.config(text=str(segs)+str(mins))
     labeltm.after(10, show_frame)

Comment: el problema esta en la parte de los segs, si gustas te puedo mandar mi código por .txt

Comment: me marca "NameError: 'sec' is not defined"

Comment: Gracias! Pero no se ve bien el código. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y agregar el emcv allí.

Comment: mmm no se como hacer que se vea mejor, intenté mejorarla, pero se sigue viendo igual :( lo mejor que pude es asi como está